# How to keep screen down on screen-door?

Tags: doors, screens, storm-door

I purchased a [vertical retractable](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Andersen-3000-Series-36-in-x-80-in-White-Right-Hand-Full-View-Retractable-Aluminum-Storm-Door-H3SER36WH/202985075) screen door from Home Depot. It’s two half glass sides, but you can pull the top one down to make it half screen and half glass.

Here are relevant pictures of the [screen-door installed](https://imgur.com/a/29mrZMm).

Whenever I pull the screen down, it slowly starts to move up, almost as if the wind is pushing it up.

Anything I can purchase and use to keep it pinned down? There is a lip on the bottom (see second picture)

Comment: I suspect there are some adjustments in the gadget to fix this problem. Have you tried their helpline, others may have the same problem, so they may have a solution.